# how to divide a column's values by the sum of multiple column values by row

Tags: r

I have a data frame as such:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
  1    1    1    1
  1    1    1    1
  1    1    1    1
  1    1    1    1
```

I would like to create 4 new columns where each is the initial columns value divided by the sum of col1-4

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col1_norm col2_norm col3_norm col4_norm
  1    1    1    1      0.25      0.25     0.25     0.25
  1    1    1    1      0.25      0.25     0.25     0.25
  1    1    1    1      0.25      0.25     0.25     0.25
  1    1    1    1      0.25      0.25     0.25     0.25
```

I've tried what I thought would be logical:

```
df$col1_norm <- df$col1 / sum(df$col1, df$col2, df$col3, df$col4)
```

But I'm realizing that simply sums all the column values and then divides

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can try `rowSums` function.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `dplyr` package and `across`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(across(col1:col5, 
                       list(norm = ~ .x / rowSums(cur_data())), 
                       .names = "{.col}_{.fn}"))
```

**Output**

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4 col1_norm col2_norm col3_norm col4_norm
1    1    1    1    1      0.25      0.25      0.25      0.25
2    1    1    1    1      0.25      0.25      0.25      0.25
3    1    1    1    1      0.25      0.25      0.25      0.25
4    1    1    1    1      0.25      0.25      0.25      0.25
```

If you columns are not consecutive then you can use another [tidyselect](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html) method like `starts_with("col")` rather than `col1:col5`.

You can also subset `cur_data()` if you don't want to row sum all the data.

---

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), col2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), col3 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), col4 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

To build the operation we can use `select()` and then `rowSums()`, after this
it is possible to use `mutate()` function to apply the operation over all df columns:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(normalized = select(., col1:col4)/select(., col1:col4) %>% 
            rowSums(na.rm = TRUE))
```

Console Output:

```
#  col1 col2 col3 col4 normalized.col1 normalized.col2 normalized.col3 normalized.col4
#1    1    1    1    1            0.25            0.25            0.25            0.25
#2    1    1    1    1            0.25            0.25            0.25            0.25
#3    1    1    1    1            0.25            0.25            0.25            0.25
#4    1    1    1    1            0.25            0.25            0.25            0.25
```

### data

```
df <- data.frame(col1=rep(1,4),
                 col2=rep(1,4),
                 col3=rep(1,4),
                 col4=rep(1,4))
```

Comment: Thank you very much dear @AlvaroMartinez I couldn't figure out the output column names and I realized I had to wrap it in a list.

Answer (score 0):

`rowSums` is what you need.

```
df$col1_norm <- df$col1 / rowSums(df[,1:4])
df$col2_norm <- df$col2 / rowSums(df[,1:4])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of it, however not much different from the code proposed above:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

df <- tribble(
  ~col1, ~col2, ~col3, ~col4,
  1,    1,   1,    1,
  1,    1,   1,    1,
  1,    1,   1,    1,
  1,    1,    1,   1
)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(sum_cols = sum(c_across(col1:col4)),
         across(col1:col4,  list(norm = ~ .x / sum_cols), .names = "{.col}_{.fn}")) %>%
  select(-sum_cols)
  

# A tibble: 4 x 8
# Rowwise: 
   col1  col2  col3  col4 col1_norm col2_norm col3_norm col4_norm
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1     1     1     1      0.25      0.25      0.25      0.25
2     1     1     1     1      0.25      0.25      0.25      0.25
3     1     1     1     1      0.25      0.25      0.25      0.25
4     1     1     1     1      0.25      0.25      0.25      0.25
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dt <- dt %>% mutate(across(.fns = ~(.)/rowSums(dt),.names = "{.col}_norm"))
```

Comment: Can you explain "{.col}_norm" - how does that find the correct columns?

Comment: Sure, `across` function has the argument `.cols`. This argument take all cols by default (when not specified).